# Singleton class with instance variable and methods in Swift (iOS)

Tags: ios, swift

So, i am creating a Singleton class as below, and i need few instance variables in this class, such that any team member can access the instance variable and get the values. To do that, i will need to initialize these instance variables to a certain value at the beginning itself.
But i get a compilation error, saying "missing argument for parameter 'doesValueExists' in call".

What exactly i m doing wrong here ?

```
class ABC_Util {

    private var doesValueExists: Bool
    private var arrValues: NSMutableArray?

    class var sharedInstance: ABC_Util {
        struct ABC_UtilSingleton {
            static let instance = ABC_Util()
        }

        return ABC_UtilSingleton.instance
    }

    init(doesValueExists: Bool, arrValues: NSMutableArray?) {
        self.doesValueExists = self.checkValueExists()
        self.arrValues = self.getArrayOfValues()
    }

    //method
    internal func checkValueExists() -> Bool {
    }

    //method
    internal func getArrayOfValues() -> NSMutableArray? {
    }

}
```

Comment: You need to return something in the functions

Comment: Your compilation error probably roots in the missing argument when calling the init, i.e. some call like ABC_Util(true, mutableArray) where you need the parameter names in the call ABC_Util(doesValueExists: true, arrValues: mutableArray).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the solution, when i tried this, worked fine!

class ABC_Util {

```
 var doesValueExists:Bool = false
 var arrValues:NSMutableArray? = nil


class var sharedInstance: ABC_Util 
{
    struct ABC_UtilSingleton 
    {
        static let instance = ABC_Util()
    }

    return ABC_UtilSingleton.instance
}

init() {

    self.doesValueExists = self.checkValueExists()
    self.arrValues = self.getArrayOfValues()
}

//method
internal func checkValueExists()-> Bool
{
    //return true/false
}

//method
internal func getArrayOfValues()-> NSMutableArray?
{
    //return array/nil
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Your initializer for ABC_Util is declared as:

```
init(doesValueExists:Bool, arrValues:NSMutableArray?) {
```

Therefore you cannot say

```
static let instance = ABC_Util()
```

The expression `ABC_Util()` would correspond to an initializer with no parameters, and you do not have such an initializer. You must say:

```
static let instance = ABC_Util(doesValueExists:someBool, arrValues:someArray)
```

(with appropriate values, of course).

Answer (score 0):

You have to use your initializer in order to initialize your variables.

```
class ABC_Util {

    private var doesValueExists:Bool
    private var arrValues:NSMutableArray?


    class var sharedInstance: ABC_Util 
    {
        struct ABC_UtilSingleton 
        {
            static let instance = ABC_Util(doesValueExists: true, arrValues: nil)
        }

        return ABC_UtilSingleton.instance
    }

    init(doesValueExists:Bool, arrValues:NSMutableArray?) {

        self.doesValueExists = doesValueExists
        self.arrValues = arrValues
    }

    //method
    internal func checkValueExists()-> Bool
    {
        return true
    }

    //method
    internal func getArrayOfValues()-> NSMutableArray?
    {
        return nil
    }
}
```

And I recommend you to change your singleton declaration to the suggested syntax

```
static let sharedInstance: ABC_Util = ABC_Util(doesValueExists: true, arrValues: nil)
```

Comment: actually, i plan to use init method as:   
init() {

        self.doesValueExists = doesValueExists
        self.arrValues = arrValues
    }    

 but when i do this, i get error -> "Use of 'self' in method call 'dosValueExists' before all stored properties are initialized”

Comment: You can't do that. `doesValueExists` and `arrValues`  are refered to class variables, not as parameters by compiler, and ini Swift you have to initialize all your variables. Maybe you can set default values to your variables, something like `doesValueExists = false` and  `arrValues = nil`

Answer (score 0):

You could use as below.

class ABC_Util {

```
private var doesValueExists:Bool = false
private var arrValues:NSMutableArray?

class var sharedInstance: ABC_Util {

    struct ABC_UtilSingleton {

        static let instance = ABC_Util(doesValueExists: false, arrValues: ["a", "b", "c"])
    }

    return ABC_UtilSingleton.instance
}
init(doesValueExists:Bool, arrValues:NSMutableArray?) {

    self.doesValueExists = self.checkValueExists()
    self.arrValues = self.getArrayOfValues()
}
//method
internal func checkValueExists()-> Bool{

    return self.doesValueExists
}
//method
internal func getArrayOfValues()-> NSMutableArray?{

return arrValues
}
```

}